# In this code example, will the AssetManager class member be garbage collected by the JVM?

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, garbage-collection

I have a situation where I interface Java with C++ code (Android - JNI/NDK).
As explained in the code comments below, I'm trying to prevent the AssetManager instance to be garbage collected (Because I'm using this instance in the native code).

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements DroidBlaster {
    // We need a reference to AssetManager (used by DroidBlaster JNI/NDK), 
    // in order to ensure that the AssetManager instance which is passed to 
    // native method DroidBlaster::create, is not garbage collected while 
    // the native object is in use. Furthermore we pass an instance of
    // AndroidLauncher (this) to the Flm::initialize method, in order to 
    // ensure this class is not garbage collected.
    private AssetManager assetManager; 

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        initialize(new Flm(App.Type.PRO, this), config);
    }

    // ...
    // ....
}
```

Now the Flm class (the one which is instantiated by the initialize method in the code above), contains a static DroidBlaster member (which has it interface implemented by the AndroidLauncher class) which is intialized in the constructor.

```
public class Flm extends Game {
    static DroidBlaster droidblaster;

    public Flm(App.Type aAppType, final DroidBlaster droidblaster) {
        super();
        App.instance.setType(aAppType);
        this.droidblaster = droidblaster;
    }

    // ...
    // ....
}
```

I'm doubting, Is this implementation correct in order to ensure, that during the existence of the Flm instance, the AssetManager member of AndroidLauncher, will never be garbage collected??

Comment: Your local `assetManager` variable in `onCreate` hides the member field of the same name - and is never used. Is that really your code / your intention?

Comment: Yes, the assetManager reference is used by the native code (C++), it is passed to a native method, than in the C++ code it is stored in a class variable. This all happens before the `initialize` call. For simplicity that code is not shown here. So I'm using the AssetManager in the C++ code, however I must watch out that my reference doesn't get garbage collected by the JVM, hence the reason for my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use an object from native code, you need a local or global JNI reference to it.  Passing the object to a native method, or extracting it from a field with JNI calls, creates a local reference.  These expire and are discarded when the thread in question returns to the VM.

If you want a reference to continue to be valid across calls into native code, you need to create a global reference with `NewGlobalRef`.  These do not expire, and must be explicitly deleted when they're no longer needed.

Attempting to preserve the object with code written in Java doesn't really make sense.  If the object is not yet visible to native code then it doesn't matter if it gets collected -- clearly nothing held a reference to it.  If the object is visible to native code, and must not be discarded, then you should create a global reference from native code.

See [JNI Tips](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#local_and_global_references) for additional information.